# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler' in Flask

Tags: python, virtualenv, apscheduler

I want to set up a `flask` server with a scheduler using `APScheduler`.

Unfortunately `flask` doesn't want to run with `APScheduler` - it crashes at the imports.

I tried `APScheduler==2.1.2` and use:

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
```

I tried also the newest `APScheduler==3.6.3` and use:

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
```

In both cases after running `flask run` I got:

```
Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\(...)\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\(...)\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'
```

I tried installing `Apscheduler` with `pip`, `pip3` and `conda` - same results. I tried `Flask-APScheduler` - same reuslts.

`PyCharm` recognizes and hints the `APScheduler` (as well as `IPython`), but `flask` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. The issue was that I have 2 `flask`s installed on my computer:

- first one is **global**
- second one is for **my venv** only

The `flask run` was executing the global one (because in `Path` environment variable there was only path to this one), but `APScheduler` is installed within my venv. I deleted the global `flask` and changed the `Path` variable to my venv. I don't know, if this is a proper way to solve it, but now it works.